# find unique minimum and maximum dates from 4 tables - php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm using wordpress and have 4 custom tables. Each of them looks like this:

```
Table1       Table2        Table3        Table4

date         date          date          date
2016-07-21   2016-11-13    2016-10-19    2016-11-18  
2016-09-16   2016-10-27    2016-11-13    2016-10-25
2016-09-09   2016-09-30    2016-07-15    2016-09-28
2016-11-11   2016-08-19    2016-11-17    2016-10-24
```

I need to find minimum date of these 4 tables and maximum date of these 4 tables. I tried to do that via below code:

```
$minViews = $wpdb->get_results("
SELECT MIN(date) as min_date FROM Table1 UNION 
SELECT MIN(date) as min_date FROM Table2 UNION 
SELECT MIN(date) as min_date FROM Table3 UNION 
SELECT MIN(date) as min_date FROM Table4");

$maxViews = $wpdb->get_results("
SELECT MAX(date) as max_date FROM Table1 UNION 
SELECT MAX(date) as max_date FROM Table2 UNION 
SELECT MAX(date) as max_date FROM Table3 UNION 
SELECT MAX(date) as max_date FROM Table4");
```

But above query returns each table's minimum and maximum date. But I need to find minimum date of **all 4 tables** and maximum date of **all 4 tables**.

Comment: I don't know why you have 4 tables, but anyway... UNION them first, and find the min and max of that subquery. (I'm not sure what you mean by 'unique ' in this context)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can always use a subquery in your FROM clause:

```
SELECT MIN(date), MAX(date) FROM
(
    SELECT date FROM Table1
    UNION SELECT date FROM Table2
    UNION SELECT date FROM Table3
    UNION SELECT date FROM Table4
) AS sq;
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks. But what if my `date` column name is different in 2 tables. For example, table1 - `date`, table2 - `ins_date`, table3 - `date`, table4 - `ins_date` @Daniel Heinrich

Comment: Doesn't matter. The first table defines the column name - in this case `Table1` defines the name of the resulting column as `date`.

Comment: I also was thinking like that but actually It matters because now it returns me `array(0) { }`. Any ideas? @Daniel Heinrich

Comment: can you show me your code?
And tell me what database you are using?

Comment: Here it is: `$minMaxViews = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT MIN(date), MAX(date) FROM( SELECT ins_date FROM table1 UNION SELECT insertion_date FROM table2 UNION SELECT ins_date FROM table3 UNION SELECT insertion_date FROM table4) AS subquery"); var_dump($minMaxViews);`. So this returns `array(0) { }`. @Daniel Heinrich

Comment: I am using wordpress database. @Daniel Heinrich

Comment: There is your problem:
Your first SELECT in you subquery is `SELECT ins_date FROM table1` meaning the column will be called `ins_date`. So you either change `MIN(date), MAX(date)` to `MIN(ins_date), MAX(ins_date)` - or you add an alias to the column in the first SELECT in your subquery.

Comment: Yes you are right. I added an alias and it worked. Thank you so much! @Daniel Heinrich